# How can I test that a ThreadLocal value was removed?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, unit-testing

How can I write a unit test to make sure a `ThreadLocal` value is removed when the thread exits?

According to [this documentation](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/new-in-net-4-5-threadlocal-values/):

> By default (i.e., trackAllValues=false), a value stored into a ThreadLocal is cleared when the ThreadLocal instance is disposed/finalized OR when the corresponding thread exits, whichever happens first.
>
> [...]
>
> So, if you set trackAllValues=true, the ThreadLocal instance will keep track of all values that have been stored into it, even if the corresponding threads are now gone.

This puts me in a bind:

- If I set `trackAllValues=false`, then I get the behavior that I want, but I cannot access `ThreadLocal.Values` in my unit test.
- If I set `trackAllValues=true`, then I can access `ThreadLocal.Values` in my unit test, but the behavior has changed.

Here is the unit test I wrote (using NUnit). It does not work for reasons outlined above.

```cs
[Test]
public void RemoveThreadLocalValueWhenThreadExits()
{
    var storage = new ThreadLocal<int>(true);

    var thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        storage.Value = 42;
    });

    thread.Start();
    thread.Join();

    // Fails, because Count == 1.
    Assert.That(storage.Values.Count, Is.EqualTo(0));
}
```

Note: the motivation behind this question is that I want to unit test a class I wrote that happens to use `ThreadLocal` internally. The implementation could change in the future, so I prefer not to omit the unit test just because "that is how ThreadLocal works."

Comment: _"the motivation behind this question is that I want to unit test a class I wrote that happens to use ThreadLocal internally. The implementation could change in the future, so I prefer not to omit the unit test just because "that is how ThreadLocal works.""_ - without seeing the actual code it is hard to tell, but if `ThreadLocal` is an internal implementation detail, you should not test it, you should test the exposed contract.

Comment: Yes, I am testing the exposed contract, not `ThreadLocal` directly. But under the hood the class uses `ThreadLocal`. This question is my attempt at a minimal reproducible example. If I can get this test to work, then I can use that information to write the actual test.

Comment: I agree with @GuruStron that only public interfaces should be tested and not internal details.

Comment: I have a class that uses `ThreadLocal` to maintain a separate big object for each thread. I'd like to test that class to make sure stale objects are cleaned up to prevent memory leaks. How would you suggest I do that? (My solution was to expose a `Count` property on my class that internally returns `myThreadLocal.Values.Count` but that did not work.)

Comment: @ewerspej and @GuruStron - I posted a new question to focus on the class under test instead of `ThreadLocal`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76220193/11838196