# How to test a class that uses ThreadLocal for memory leaks?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, unit-testing, nunit

I have this class:

```cs
public class DataProvider
{
    private readonly ThreadLocal<List<string>> data = new ThreadLocal<List<string>>(() => new List<string>());

    public List<string> Data => this.data.Value;
}
```

I'd like to test this class for memory leaks (e.g. old lists not getting removed when the thread exits). I am not concerned that `ThreadLocal` is not doing its job, but rather I am concerned that the implementation of this class may be changed in the future.

I tried the following solution, but it did not work, because setting `trackAllValues=true` changes the behavior of `ThreadLocal` to NOT remove values when the thread exits ([source](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/new-in-net-4-5-threadlocal-values/)).

```cs
public class DataProvider
{
    // Set `trackAllValues=true` to support unit test.
    private readonly ThreadLocal<List<string>> data = new ThreadLocal<List<string>>(() => new List<string>(), true);

    public List<string> Data => this.data.Value;

    // Added to support unit test.
    public int Count => this.data.Values.Count;
}

[Test]
public void RemoveStackWhenThreadExitsToPreventMemoryLeak()
{
    var target = new DataProvider();

    var thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        target.Data.Add("foo");
    });

    thread.Start();
    thread.Join();

    // Fails, because count == 1.
    Assert.That(target.Count, Is.EqualTo(0));
}
```

Note: I previously asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76212075/11838196), but commenters did not like how I framed that question.

Comment: _"but commenters did not like how I framed that question"_ - who said that we didn't like it? The question was not even closed =)

Comment: I would argue that this would not be easy to test. I would look into skipping handling the `ThreadLocal` and looking into sideeffects. For example invoking the metod/creating an object many times (and/or with big strings) and analyzing result of `GC.GetTotalMemory(true)` (with some delta). Also note that in the modern day and age using `ThreadLocal` can be dangerous (`async` can return in any thread pool thread without sync context, thread pool AFAIK does not clear thread storage).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I test that a ThreadLocal value was removed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76212075/how-can-i-test-that-a-threadlocal-value-was-removed)

Comment: I never used ThreadLocal (and +1 to @GuruStron comment of not using it due to `async`), but looking at the documentation `data.Values.Count` sounds like just thread counter as there seem to be no provision to remove items when `trackAllValues` is set... I'd recommend to make state just instance field (no problems with lifetime) or use cache (which would be testable).

Comment: Overall it feels like *this question* tries to test .Net functionality (to confirm ThreadLocal released on thread exit) - this is rarely useful (unless you found a bug and need to report it)... Maybe an [edit] to clarify why you expect "old lists not getting removed when the thread exits" not to happen could help. (It is possible you are looking for `Dispose` call on the object you really want to store in that ThreadLocal... - consider to adjust you [mre] if it is the case ).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - I want to test this class to protect against future changes to this class, not because I don't trust the `ThreadLocal` implementation. I edited the question to clarify this point. Also, can you explain your recommendations above? By "instance field" do you mean remove `ThreadLocal` so `DataProvider` has a single `List` and then scope `DataProvider` to the request or something like that? What would the "cache" implementation look like? What caching class/library do you have in mind? Would I have separate data per thread? Request? How would that make it testable?

Comment: Yes, I suggest considering removing `ThreadLocal`... "Scope DataProvider to the request" part of your comment is confusing/concerning - `ThreadLocal` is not compatible with code that has `async`/`await` anywhere and most of code that deals with "requests" would have those at least in infrastructure layers...

Comment: For caching just regular MemoryCache may be enough - inject it with DI from a test and make sure count/iteration shows expected results... Injecting new cache per "request" would solve "not removed at the end of request" problem without any extra efforts...